# Angular Custom Async Validator stays in pending state

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, asynchronous

I have a Custom Validator that validates if a user's email is unique or not.

**I've searched for related topic on stackoverflow and internet, but no help**

when I'm giving input in the form (sending the request), the request stays at pending state and doesnot resolves.

I've tested the backend in postman, its working as expected, the problem is at client or angular side.

The Validation function is as follows:

```
emailUniqueValidator (control: AbstractControl): Promise<{[key: string]: any}> | Observable<{[key: string]: any}> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.userService.checkEmailUnique(control.value).subscribe((response: Response) => {
        const body = response.json();
        if (body.found === false) {
          resolve(null); // email is unique
        } else {
          reject({emailUniqueValidator: true}); // email is not unique
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

When i'm changing the form control's value, the pending class appears, but it sticks in forever instead of getting resolved.

I have the email form control as follows:

```
'email': new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email
      ], this.emailUniqueValidator.bind(this)
),
```

And my User service is as follows:

```
checkEmailUnique (email: string): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/user/email', {email}, { withCredentials: true });
  }
```

Why The validator is not resolving in time and staying pending forever?

**EDIT:**

The following code is getting value from the service just fine, i've checked it by logging the response into the console.

If the email is not present in the database, then it is getting resolved just fine, but if the email is already present, it is throwing an error and the state remains pending.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.userService.checkEmailUnique(control.value).subscribe((response: Response) => {
        console.log(response);
        response.json().found ? reject({emailUniqueValidator: true}) : resolve(null);
      }, (error: any) => reject({emailUniqueValidator: true}));
});
```

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13200

Comment: has your component ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush ?

Comment: `emailUniqueValidator (control: AbstractControl): Promise<{[key: string]: any}> | Observable<{[key: string]: any}> {

    return this.userService.checkEmailUnique(control.value).pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(value => value.body.found ? {emailUniqueValidator: true} : null)
    );

  }`

This code is working fine for me @Eldar

Answer (score 21):

The observable never completes.

Try adding `.first()` at the end.

```
emailUniqueValidator (control: AbstractControl): Observable<{[key: string]: any}> {
    return this.userService.checkEmailUnique(control.value)
               .map(r => r.json())
               .map(r => (r.found) ? {emailUniqueValidator: true} : null)
               .first();
 }
```

Comment: The more recent rxjs version looks like this: `this.userService.checkEmailUnique(control.value).pipe(map(r => r.json()), take(1))` Some details left out to keep it readable, as code formatting options are limited in comments apparently.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I removed `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and it worked. An example [is here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xbbpnyokqoo).

Answer (score 2):

make sure your "status code from" service is 200 any case

```
var user = _appRepository.GetUserByUserName(username);
if (user != null)

    return Ok(user );
}
return Ok();
```

this is from asp.net core api. when user not available send empty `Ok()`. if angular catches 404 or 400, pending always show.

```
export function uniqueUsernameValidator(userService: UserService): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (c: AbstractControl): Observable<{ [key: string]: any } | null> => {
    return userService.getUserByUsername(c.value).pipe(
      map(users => {
        console.log(users)
        if (users) {
          return { 'unique': true};
        }else {
          return null
        }
      })
    )
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you going through the promise wrapping an observable head ache? try it like this:

```
emailUniqueValidator (control: AbstractControl): Observable<{[key: string]: any}> {
    return this.userService.checkEmailUnique(control.value)
               .map(r => r.json())
               .map(r => (r.found) ? {emailUniqueValidator: true} : null);
 }
```

Comment: I tried your code, but the state is still pending, can you tell why is this happening?

Comment: you should use the do() operator to debug, see if anything ever makes it through, this should work, some issue is somewhere else.

Comment: It's because the observable never completes. 
You have to complete the observable with first() or take(1).

Comment: @Hypenate no, the original question shows `checkEmailUnique` is an http call

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question has subscription only to successful resolve of observable, so if observable fails or completes without emit - you do not handle that, promise's resolve and reject are never called.

1. do not wrap into promise, angular async validator works with observables
2. add catchError(() => of(false)) to observable's pipe to convert failure into some kind of response.
3. be sure to convert response into ValidationErrors | null type response: service should do conversion and typification of response after calling http.post / http.get; your validator should further convert simple service response into ValidationErrors

- data services making requests should always complete after first emit, so adding take(1) or first() to pipe is excessive in this case (and actually does not change anything, as validation is resolved on first emit by angular)