# FormGroup with pending status within custom stepper

Tags: angular, forms, validation, asynchronous

I'm trying to force an update on the validators of all the form groups of a custom stepper just before the registration at the end of the final step, like so :

```js
public async register(): Promise<void> {
    // do stuff

    // update validity of all forms from all steps
    const stepForms = this.stepFactories.map(step => step.form);
    stepForms.forEach(group => {
        if (group !== null && group !== undefined) {
            this.updateValueAndValidity(group);
        }
    });

    // check if any form is KO
    if (stepForms.every(form => form.valid || form.disabled)) {
        try {
            result = await this.registrationService.register(model);
        } catch (error) {
            // do stuff
        }

        // do stuff
    }
}
```

One of the form groups contain another formGroup with an asynchronous validator with 2 calls to the server which works as follow:

```js
export function fooAsyncValidator(fooService: FooService, fooParams: FooParams): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (group: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
        const fooControlVal1 = group.get('FooVal1').value;
        const fooControlVal2 = group.get('FooVal2').value;
    
        // do stuff

        let availableFoo: number;
        // first call to server, which is answered according to chrome debugger
        return fooService.getAvailableFoo(fooParams).pipe(
            flatMap((avFoo: number) => {
                availableFoo = avFoo;

                // second call to server which is answered after I get to check the validity
                return fooService.getConsumedFoo(fooParam, availableFoo);
            }),
            map((consumedFoo: number) => {
                // do stuff with available Foo and consumedFoo
                if (/* stuff */) {
                    return { availableFooError: true };
                }

                return null;
            }),
        );
    }
}
```

According to chrome debugger, when I apply the `updateValueAndValidity` on this form group, the first call, `fooService.getAvailableFoo(...)`, is answered on time, but the second call, `fooService.getConsumedFoo(...)`, is answered later. This result in the status of the form group being "PENDING".

I have found a [similar subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796642/angular-custom-async-validator-stays-in-pending-state) connected to [this tutorial](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-forms-create-async-validator-directive-dd3fd026cb45) but I don't really understand how to apply it to my current problem as I am quite new to Angular.

I found out in another part of the code that use a [CdkStepper](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/cdk/stepper) that setting the value of [selectedIndex](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/bca634b3dbeb6d71eff17524fc494613bf0c52b5/src/cdk/stepper/stepper.ts#L290) to the number of a step with the same form group would correctly update the validity of the form.

For reference, here is the code of the `updateValueAndValidity` custom method, which apply `updateValueAndValidity` on each fromGroup and formControl recursively:

```js
private updateValueAndValidity(group: FormGroup): void {
    group.updateValueAndValidity({ emitEvent: false });
    for (const field in group.controls) { // 'field' is a string
        const control = group.get(field);
        if (control) {
            if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
                updateValueAndValidity(control);
        } else {
            if (control.disabled) {
                control.enable({ emitEvent: false });
                control.updateValueAndValidity({ emitEvent: false });
                if (!control['invalidActived'] || !control.invalid) {
                    control.disable({ emitEvent: false });
                }
            } else {
                control.updateValueAndValidity({ emitEvent: false });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**In summary:** When I update the value and validity of a form group with 2 calls to the server, the status switch to pending as one the 2 isn't answered yet. I want to know how to wait for the pending to end.

**Edit:** Reworked a bit of the question layout and changed title since main stepper is a custom one, not a CdkStepper.

**Edit 2:** So I found [this github thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13200) but it doesn't seem to get a definitive answer before being closed...

**Edit 3:** Found another lead in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49516084/reactive-angular-form-to-wait-for-async-validator-complete-on-submit):

- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63263579) seems to be interesting, but I would need to include all four formGroups in the subscribe => not sure how to do it yet
- the last answer hint at [this github request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31021) wherein the author describe his custom solution

I just found this code in the app I'm working on, burried inside a component:

```js
export function awaitAsyncValidator(form: FormGroup): Observable<number> {
    return timer(0, 500).pipe(
        tap((timerCount: number) => {
            if (timerCount > 200) {
                throw new Error('The form is blocked in "pending" status.');
            }
        }),
        filter(() => !form.pending),
        take(1),
    );
}
```

It is used with a Subscription objet attached to it in a subscribe.
Currently testing it out.

Comment: Just a guess: try and use `concatMap` instead of `flatMap` in your `fooAsyncValidator`

Comment: I'm aware it would be better to use `concatMap` since `flatMap` is deprecated. However, it doesn't change anything after testing this solution =/ and sadly my work is currently limited to bug fixing not refactoring code.

Still thank you.

Comment: As for your Edit 2, the "definitive" answer from that thead seems to be in this [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13200#issuecomment-371440273) : be sure your observable always completes.

Comment: @Ibsn, I tried to understand this comment and how to apply it to my case but that doesn't seems to be it yet =(
However I have found some other leads I'm adding in Eddit 3 right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the correct way to update the validity of all my forms.
The following function allows to wait for the pending status to end.

```js
export function awaitAsyncValidator(form: FormGroup): Observable<number> {
    return timer(0, 500).pipe(
        tap((timerCount: number) => {
            if (timerCount > 200) {
                throw new Error('The form is blocked in "pending" status.');
            }
        }),
        filter(() => !form.pending),
        take(1),
    );
}
```

Then using `awaitAsyncValidator().subscribe(...);` instead of `await awaitAsyncValidator();`:

```js
public async register(): Promise<void> {
    // do stuff

    // update validity of all forms from all steps
    const stepForms: FormGroup[] = this.stepFactories.map(step => step.form);
    const globalForm = new FormGroup({});
    for (let [index,group] of stepForms.entries()) {
        if (!isNullOrUndefined(group)) {
            globalForm.addControl(index.toString(), group);
        }
    }
    updateValueAndValidity(globalForm);
    awaitAsyncValidator(globalForm).subscribe(
        async () => {
            // check if any form is KO
            if (globalForm.valid || globalForm.disabled) {
                try {
                    result = await this.registrationService.register(model);
                } catch (error) {
                    // do stuff
                }

                // do stuff
            }
        });
}
```

Thanks @Ibsn for your help.